# OWIN WEBAPI and SQLite database moving to Azure

Tags: sqlite, azure, asp.net-web-api, owin, azure-worker-roles

I have an OWIN implementation of backend that hosts a set of WebApiController as a REST WEB API. These controllers use SQLite database. 
Now we plan to move them to Azure, probably host them in a WorkerRole and start our OWIN app in OnStart(). With a bit of research I found this approach is a common practice to host OWIN apps in Azure.

The question I have is now related to database. I want to use RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource().Root and sync latest database with Azure blob storage on the role start. And then the OWIN app can communicate to the database from that point on.
And once the role is going to be stopped, I sync back the database on local to the Azure blob storage.

Question: Is this a good practice? Any suggestion on this scenario to use SQLite in a WorkerRole?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQLite your role needs to access the file, so you need to use LocalStorage as you mentioned to write in files when you are in Azure. Have a look at http://blog.codingoutloud.com/2011/06/12/azure-faq-can-i-write-to-the-file-system-on-windows-azure/ for more information regarding the API.

Comment: I have similar situation. What would be the difference if my OWIN Web API App is accessing DB that I am hosting as Azure SQL DB ?

Comment: The difference is the database, in this case SQLite is the database, and the file is hosted either local to the Web API or somewhere in blob storage.  But when you use Azure SQL DB, it is the Azure implementation of MS SQL server not SQLite.